# How to display an unbreaking string in next line with help of css

Tags: html, css, string

Here is my code sample

```
<td width="40%">Field One</td>
<td width="30%">THISISAVERYLONGTEXTSOMEMORECHARACTERSTOMAKEITALITTLELONGERTHISISJUSTFORTESTING</td>
<td width="30%">Field Three</td>
```

Unable to bring the long text to next line I have also used these following methods in the `<td>` tag. but same result.
These are :

1. `style="width:200px;"`
2. `style="width:100px; overflow:hidden"`
3. `style="word-wrap:break-word;`

I don't want to scroll the text. Please suggest some option.

Comment: I fear the answer is "not possible with CSS". You'll have to use JavaScript to actually cut the text to chunks i.e. push spaces.

Comment: can you make it fiddle

Comment: I too think it's not gonna be possible only by CSS. Let me do some more trials.

Answer (score 1):

hope it will help you

```
 td {
 padding: 0;
word-break: break-all;
text-align: center;

}
table{

width:100%
}
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/nVZHp/3/

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use a soft-hyphen ­ at intervals during your long text string? For Example

```
<td width="40%">Field One</td>
<td width="30%">THIS&shy;IS&shy;A&shy;VERY&shy;LONG&shy;TEXT&shy;SOME&shy;MORE&shy;CHARACTERS&shy;TO&shy;MAKE&shy;IT&shy;A&shy;LITTLE&shy;LONGER&shy;THIS&shy;IS&shy;JUST&shy;FOR&shy;TESTING</td>
<td width="30%">Field Three</td>
```

If required, the bowser will automatically split the string wherever you have the soft-hyphen and move the rest on to the next line.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6AENx/)

Comment: the demo doesn't bring the long text to next line please check

Comment: Apologies, Posted the wrong Fiddle Link - I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `word-wrap: break-word` doesn't work with elements that have `display: table-cell`. That includes `<td>`. You can't resolve it by adding `word-wrap` directly to the `td` but you can wrap its content with additional `div`. The problem will still occur until you set a fixed width for the `div`. I believe this is the only way to achieve this:

```
<td width="30%">
    <div>
        THISISAVERYLONGTEXTSOMEMORECHARACTERSTOMAKEITALITTLELONGERTHISISJUSTFORTESTING
    </div>
</td>
```

Then the CSS:

```
td > div {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 150px; /* or whatever else */
}
```

You can't achieve this when relying **only** on percentage widths. When using percent, the `div` will still spread to fit its content in one line. The `td`, then `tr` and `table` will follow.

Here's the DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nVZHp/2/

Answer (score 0):

You have a non-breaking text that can not be carried forward to the next line. If you want to move the text to the next line, insert a space in the line.

Comment: that's exactly i do not want, the text is without space, how can it be done to break the word to next line after it exceeds the edge of it's width using CSS only

Answer (score 0):

CSS might not be cross browser enough or cause some side effects. For those who want alternative, here is pure JavaScript way to force spaces into the long string, thus wrapping it as well.

```
var cellID = "cell1";
var whatToPush = " ";
var pushAfter = 10;
window.onload = function() {
    var oCell = document.getElementById(cellID);
    var oTable = oCell.parentNode;
    while (oTable && oTable.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== "table")
        oTable = oTable.parentNode;
    if (!oTable) {
        alert("Fatal error: " + cellID + " is not a table cell");
        return;
    }
    var availableWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;
    var tableWidth = oTable.offsetWidth;
    var counter = 0;
    while (tableWidth > availableWidth) {
        if (counter > 100) {
            alert("Warning: word wrap forcing took too many iterations");
            break;
        }
        var rawHTML = oCell.innerHTML;
        var index = rawHTML.length - (pushAfter * (counter + 1));
        if (counter > 0)
            index -= whatToPush.length;
        rawHTML = rawHTML.substring(0, index) + whatToPush + rawHTML.substring(index, rawHTML.length);
        oCell.innerHTML = rawHTML;
        tableWidth = oTable.offsetWidth;
        counter++;
    }
};
```

The constants in the beginning are pretty much intuitive, it works on a single cell given its ID and pushing some fixed string (e.g. blank space but can also be different string) after fixed amount of characters, counting backwards. (end of contents will split first)

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/jXgA3/).